# set-payment-information throwing 500 of stripe payment Magento 2.3.5

Tags: magento, stripe-payments, checkout

I have an website with Magento 2.3.5. I want to implement stripe payment gateway in Magento checkout page. I have installed stripe extension successfully and enter public and Secret key of stripe with test mode from admin panel. But when I add item into cart and go to checkout page and select stripe as payment method to place order then browser console throwing error like this
[image]

When I click "Place Order" button to place order the browser console throwing error like this
[image]

Please help me how to solve the issue and place order successfully.

Thank You

Comment: would you mind sharing the HTTP500 error message? you can either expand the next to the `POST` keyword or look at the network tab by clicking on the link in your console

Comment: By clicking on console link I got error like this
<response>
<message>Request does not match any route.</message>
<trace/>
</response>